# platformResourceLoader inserts resources multiple times

Tags: lightning-web-components, platformresourceloader

We are building Lightning Web Components for a Community and we're leveraging a 3rd party library to help with some charts/widgets. Each chart is it's own component and uses the platformResourceLoader to load the required resources (as below)

```
        Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, communityDashboards + '/css/main.css'),
        loadStyle(this, devExtreme + '/dx.common.css'),
        loadStyle(this, devExtreme + '/dx.greenmist.css'),
        loadScript(this, jquery341 + '/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'),
        loadScript(this, devExtreme + '/dx.all.js')
    ])
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Successfully loaded Static Resources');
            this.renderPie();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error loading Static Resources');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

We've noticed the platformResourceLoader loads our resources multiple times rather than checking if the resource is already loaded. This appears to be a shift away from how Aura handled it, which was a one time load.

See below for the script/link tags that appear multiple times when 2 components are on the page, or when we navigate between pages that have components on them.

[image: Duplicate script/link tags for each component]

Does this look like a bug or shift in how LWC handles this? If it's intended, is there a recommended way of checking the resource is loaded? For the time being we are loading the resources in a single component (in our footer) as a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much back and forth with Salesforce on this, it has been raised as a platform issue. You can follow the resolution of this at the following Known Issues link:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YoFLQA0